How to forcefully reload and clean data in Shopify JS?
I’ve trying for a few days to solve this and couldn’t. I need my page to reload and forget about the previously set values in some functions. I tried many ways to do so but none have been working in my Shopify discount.js code.
I tried making the page reload and clear cache, but it didn’t work.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // Clean local cache when loading
    sessionStorage.clear();
    localStorage.clear();

    // Call oldPrice to reset prices
    oldPrice();

In the way above it doesn’t work, but when I use a click event and location.reload like below it works fine:
coupon_tag.addEventListener('click', () => {
    location.reload();
    oldPrice();
});


Try this solution:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    if (localStorage.getItem("reloadForClean") === "true") {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        localStorage.clear();
        localStorage.setItem("reloadForClean", "false"); 
        oldPrice(); 
    }
});

coupon_tag.addEventListener('click', () => {
    localStorage.setItem("reloadForClean", "true"); 
    window.location.reload();
});

